# can't react-native init : Unable to find React Native files. Make sure "react-native" module is installed

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I can't init my new react native app. Here is the error after doing `react-native init myapp` :

`Unable to find React Native files. Make sure "react-native" module is installed in your project dependencies.. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more detail`

I already tried to reinstall react-native cli and use community cli, but doesn't work.

//EDIT:

I had to `npm react-native -g install` and it works again

Comment: If you have solved the problem with the answer below, you should choose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does `npm list -g` shows react-native as an installed package?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g react-native` didn't do it for me, as this adds the legacy CLI.

`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` to remove it, then `yarn global add @react-native-community/cli` to install the latest got me started.